# Google Sheets API returns null in Release version of APK

Tags: java, android, apk, google-sheets-api

I developed an app and pressed "Generate Signed APK..." with release version. Of course, it worked well and it gave me an apk file. I put this `MyAPP.apk` file in my phone, installed and ran. I opened well as well as I expected just like I did in "Run", which is in Android Studio for testing. But, Google API returns null without any error, logs or "Reporting error" in Google API console.

Let me introduce this problem in detail.

### Situation 1. Run in Android Studio (Press button) (Same as Instant Run)

This works well. It returns same values in Google sheets. Run as I expected.

### Situation 2. Generate Signed APK and download in my phone

I put 'key store path', 'key store password', 'key alias', 'key password' and checked both V1, V2. This method gave me an apk file. So I download this apk file in my phone and installed. (Not uploaded on Play store. Just put APK file in phone with USB-port)

### Situation 2. Problem happened. Return null.

In my app, identify QR code and get values from Google sheets which I already made.

But, this returns null even though Running in Anrorid Studio works well.

=================================

Is there any differences in Google Sheets between "Run" in android studio and "APK released version"??

Comment: This shouldn't be happening AFAIK.  When you run the app from Android Studio, though, doesn't it already install the app on your Android phone?  When you launch the app using that version, does everything work?

Comment: Sorry for unclear English. My app works well in "Run" with Android Studio. So, I think "Oh, this works well. I can publish this app to my co-workers. But I don't need to upload this app on Google Play-store right now." So, I build APK files as I mentioned with Android studio - build - Generate Signed APK for giving apk file to my friend. Before sending mail, I have to check if my apk file built well. So, I downloaded this apk file with USB in my phone. But! Not! Working! So, I was confused. I turn on Android studio again, Press "Run" button. But in this situation, Working well!!

Comment: You didn't answer my question.  What happens when you run the app from the icon which Android Studio installed from a previous connected run?

Comment: So, I thought "Oh, there is something problem with building APK file" So, I tried to make another APK file and did. But not working. I read the log what happened. but there is no error just return null. what the hell...

Comment: I uninstalled my app before download apk file or "Run" in Android studio always...

Comment: OK...but can you run that installed app in standalone mode to see if it works?

Comment: Of course. It opened well. Good splash screen as I expected. Good loading screen, Good QR code reading, Good instruction. But, after reading QR-code, returns null. (QRcode is an URL like docs.google.com/spreadsheet/d/~~~~~ )

Comment: So now this is very strange, because you're saying that if you run from Android Studio, it works, but if you run the same installed app, it doesn't work.  Maybe step through your code in debug mode to see what is happening and/or look at Logcat.

Comment: What I want to ask is... "Is there any differences between debug mode and release mode within Google-Sheets API?" I think this is the only reason why this problem happened....

Comment: There could be all sorts of differences.  For instance, maybe somewhere in your code you are waiting for an API response from Google.  In debug mode, perhaps you hit a breakpoint, in which case the call can complete, while in run mode, that doesn't happen.

Comment: Oh.. "time-out".. Is there any possibilities that I had some mistakes in setting google console?

Comment: I don't know...I would more suspect your Java code actually.  In any case, it sounds like you found the root cause of the problem, or at least part of it.

Answer (score 0):

## SHA1 Finger print Problem

There was mistake in console.cloud.google.com/ O-Auth. We have to put SHA1 fingerprint Hash **not debug.keystore but Custom keystore which is .jks** (for release)